# How to validate TextInput values in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, validation, reactjs, react-native

for example, While entering an email in the TextInput, it should validate and display the error message. where the entered email is valid or not

[image]

Comment: What are you using to display the error messages and exclamation marks when input is invalid? Thx in advance

Comment: Yeah what is the black popup prompt you are using?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use a regex to check if the mail entered is valid.

**Regex function**

```
validateEmail = (email) => {
  var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
};
```

**Submit text input function**

```
onSubmit = () => {
if (!this.validateEmail(this.state.text_input_email)) {
  // not a valid email
} else {
  // valid email
}
```

Comment: This rejex does not support : email@[123.123.123.123]

Comment: I need to validate without submitting the form. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can validate your input value using `onBlur` event on `TextInput`
You can apply your regex or check conditions on this event.

Like this:

```
<TextInput
      onBlur= () => {
        //Conditions or Regex
      }
/>
```

In your case,
Regex function:

```
validateEmail = (email) => {
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
};
```

Text Input Code:

```
<TextInput
  onBlur= () => {
    if (!this.validateEmail(this.state.text_input_email)) {
       // not a valid email
    } else {
       // valid email
    }
  }
/>
```