# Form validation in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native

I wanted to implement a basic form with text inputs, segment control and submit button. Now I want to validate the text inputs to either display error or move to next page on click of submit button. How to implement this design or any tool for the same?

Comment: Change 'How to implement this design?' to 'Which tool should I use?' and you will get more upvotes;) 
And also you can check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147276/how-to-validate-textinput-values-in-react-native

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this project it has good patterns for form validation:

https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native

Answer (score 0):

1] Check below project.It has good example for form validation :
[Github Project](https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-material-ui-form-validator) 
 2] Example/Demo of above project :
[Live Demo](https://newoldmax.github.io/react-material-ui-form-validator/)